# .Net Core Console Logging not appearing

Tags: c#, .net-core

Found this [article](https://blog.gerardbeckerleg.com/posts/how-to-add-microsofts-console-log-provider-to-dot-net-core-2-console-application-using-the-built-in-service-provider/) on .Net logging in a console app but it's not working for me. The sample log doesn't appear in the console.

I am using the latest logging packages

**The References**

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="3.1.7" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

**The Code**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // instantiate DI and configure logger
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(cfg => cfg.AddConsole())
            .AddTransient<Program>()
            .Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(cfg => cfg.MinLevel = LogLevel.Information)
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        // get instance of logger
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
        // use the logger
        logger.LogInformation("Woo Hooo");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Unsure if this is actually relevant or not, but the example you linked to has:         var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection().AddLogging(cfg => cfg.AddConsole()).Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(cfg => cfg.MinLevel=LogLevel.Debug).BuildServiceProvider(); You've added "AddTransient" to the logger service. Could be an issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your configuration is correct, the provider just doesn't get enough time to flush the output before you exit the main thread:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // instantiate DI and configure logger
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(cfg => cfg.AddConsole())
            .AddTransient<Program>()
            .Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(cfg => cfg.MinLevel = LogLevel.Information)
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        // get instance of logger
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogInformation("Woo Hooo");

        // This will allow enough time to flush
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image]

Additionally, I do not think that you need `.AddTransient<Program>()` unless you intend on creating more than one `Program` instance.

Comment: OK, but what's the correct way to that? It seems pretty unreasonable to require a `ReadLine` to flush the logs.

Answer (score 2):

Dispose of your ServiceCollection before exiting. That'll trigger disposal of your services, which, in turn, will flush the logs.

If you're in C# 8+, just add "using" in front of your `var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()` line. That's literally the only change required to the code you had.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // instantiate DI and configure logger
        using var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(cfg => cfg.AddConsole())
            .AddTransient<Program>()
            .Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(cfg => cfg.MinLevel = LogLevel.Information)
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        // get instance of logger
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
        // use the logger
        logger.LogInformation("Woo Hooo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` NuGet package and try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
            builder.AddFilter("*.Program", LogLevel.Information)
                   .AddConsole());

        ILogger logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
        logger.LogInformation("Woo Hooo");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This is how logging fundamentally works in .NET Core 3.

Or using a service provider:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(x => x.AddFilter("*.Program", LogLevel.Information)
                .AddConsole())
            .BuildServiceProvider();

        ILogger<Program> logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
        logger.LogInformation("Woo Hooo");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure he wants to use the logger factories that were built for Dependency Injection.

Comment: @Andy: I added an example using the `ServiceProvider` and `GetService`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddLogging(cfg => cfg.AddConsole()
                             .AddFilter(lvl => lvl == LogLevel.Information))
        .AddTransient<Program>()
        .BuildServiceProvider();
    // get instance of logger
    var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

The NuGet package`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` write to the console from a background thread :
https://github.com/dotnet/extensions/blob/v3.1.7/src/Logging/Logging.Console/src/ConsoleLoggerProcessor.cs

The code is open source, then don't hesitate to open the source.

In your code, the program close and the background thread is killed before it write the log. You can add a sleep to wait the log message :

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // instantiate DI and configure logger
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddLogging(cfg => cfg.AddConsole())
            .AddTransient<Program>()
            .Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(cfg => cfg.MinLevel = LogLevel.Information)
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        // get instance of logger
        var logger = serviceProvider.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
        // use the logger
        logger.LogInformation("Woo Hooo");
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    }
}
```